# Как сделать, чтобы тег p или span не переносился?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, чтобы тег p или span не переносился?

Answer (score 2):

```
p, span { display: inline; }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
p, span { white-space: nowrap; }
```

Это если надо, чтобы текст внутри не переносился

Answer (score 1):

Тег *span* - inline-элемент. По умолчанию, если в css не указано блочное отображение, он и так не переносится.

Для тега *p*:

```
<p style="display:inline">123</p>
```